# ASP.NET - How to check value of a textbox in a user control from a page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an aspx page that contains a user control. The user control has a textbox and the page has a submit button.

How can I check if the textbox in the user control is not null and display an alert if it is - from the page?

Comment: Add an RequiredFieldValidator into your UserControl. You might also want to add an property to it whether or not the textbox can be empty(`Validator.Enabled`).

Comment: jQuery is awesome framwork of javascript but you must bulletproof your code and application. Implementing validation through javascript/jquery is not enough coz that not gonna work if javascript is disabled on the client browser, so better to put serverside validation as well along with javascript validation.However `RequiredFieldValidator` but both javascript and serverside validation all at once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily handle it using jquery. Just handle the onclick javascript event of the input button:

```
$('#yourBtn').click(function(event) 
{        
    if($("#yourTxtbox").val().length > 0) 
    { 
        //do something

    } 
    else
    {
       alert("empty textbox");            
       event.preventDefault(); //prevent button click
    } 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a RequiredFieldValidator. While Giorgio's jquery method will work, it is only client side validation, so if the user has javascript disabled, it will not work. A RequiredFieldValidator will cover both client and server side validation and doesn't require writing any javascript (if all your validating is that the field is required).

```
<asp:Label ID="MyTextBoxLabel" AssociatedControlID="MyTextBox" runat="server">MyValue</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox ID="MyTextBox" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="MyTextBoxRequiredValidator" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="MyTextBox" 
    Display="Dynamic"
    ErrorMessage="Please enter a value">
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

There are also many other out of the box validators such as:

- [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx)
- [RangeValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator.aspx)
- [RegularExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx)
- [CompareValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator.aspx)

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479013.aspx for more info